# Возврат на активити с TabHost на Tab нажатый по умолчанию

Tags: android, tab

Есть `activity` с `TabHost` и тремя `Tab`:

```
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        //tabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab 1");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab1Econom.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab 2");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab2Normal.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab 3");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab3Vip.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);// таб по умолчанию при создании

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
```

На табах три `TabActivity` с кнопками входа на другие `activity`.
Проблема в том,что при выходе с кнопок, возвращаемся в главное `activity` с табом по умолчанию. Как можно сделать,чтобы возвращалось не на `Tab` по умолчанию, а на `Tab` на котором была нажата кнопка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаём переменную `int nomerTab`; В интерфейсе обрабатываем нажатие,и заполняем переменную,которую вставляем в таб по умолчанию:

```
    tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("ЭКОНОМ");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab1Econom.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("НОРМА");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab2Normal.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("VIP");
    tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab3Vip.class));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(nomerTab);// таб по умолчанию при создании

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
            if (tag.equals("tag1")) {
                nomerTab = 0;
            }
            if (tag.equals("tag2")) {
                nomerTab = 1;
            }
            if (tag.equals("tag3")) {
                nomerTab = 2;
            }
        }
    });
```